# How to avoid unwanted line breaks when having parallel columns?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to centralize parallel columns. So that's why I'm using a wrapper. However when I want to have a margin-top or a line break in one single column, it affects the parallel columns as well, which I do not want to be affected.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="column-header">
            <br>
            <p>A header</p>          
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="column-header">
                <p>A header</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="column-header">
                <p>A header</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <div class="column-header">
                <p>A header</p>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now it looks like this:

A header   A header   A header  A header

Some text

I want it to be like this:

```
         A header   A header   A header
```

A header

Some text

Comment: Not sure, but I think this should be managed by CSS and not HTML. So, with CSS, you can probably set up padding and margin which can help you create layout that has text in the center.

Comment: Please add your CSS to the question

Comment: I would look into using [`display: flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) on `.row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one way is using [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) and the css classes .row and .col-md-4 or just use a  table-tag in your html code instead of div's.

If you want to become your page responsive, use Bootstrap. Else use the table tag.

**Boostrap**

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></head>
<body>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4"> Text1 or other div's </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"> Text2 or other div's </div>
      <div class="col-md-4"> Text3 or other div's </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">Another Text and row</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Table-Tag**

```html
<table width="100%" style="text-align:center;">
  <tr>
    <td> Text 1 </td>
    <td> Text 2 </td>
    <td> Text 3 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="3" style="text-align: left;"> Text 4 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I hope that is your desired answer.

Regards.